# Weighted Average of subsets in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame in R with 5 columns. The 1st column contains a list of numbers from 0-200. The second column contains a list of numbers to be weighted, and the 3rd column contains the weights for the items in the second column. My problem is I want to divide the 1st column into sections: (0,50],(50,100],(100,150], and (150,200] and then find the weighted average for the data in each of those intervals.

I could first divide the data into those intervals individually, and create a new data frame, and then calculate the weighted average of the 2nd and 3rd column vectors in each new data frame, but that would require me going through the data four times and with a data frame as large as the one I have, that's too inefficient. In addition, for future functions, I'll need even more intervals so it'll take even longer.

Is there any way to divide it up in only one run-through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = 0:200, x2=rnorm(201), x3=rnorm(201))
s <- c(0,rep(1:4, each=50)) # create vector to split by
dfs <- split(df,s) # split it
dfs <- dfs[2:5]
lapply(dfs, function(tmp) {  # apply weighted mean to splits
    weighted.mean(tmp[,2],tmp[,3])
})
```

I updated the above to exclude the number `0`, which it seems like you don't want to include.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This method is just what I was looking for.

Comment: And also, in case you didn't know, sort(rep(1:4,50)) can be written like this: rep(1:4, each=50)

Comment: @kng I always forget about `each`! Updated.